# transition didnt work on click function

Tags: jquery, css

function onclick didnt show the content with transition.
but function hide, hide the content with the transition.
please help me why my show function didnt work with transition

```
function show_content(){
    $(".sidebar").off( "webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend" );
    $('.single-page').addClass('hidden');
  if(!$('.sidebar').hasClass('sidebar-show')){
    $('.sidebar').removeClass('hidden').addClass('sidebar-show');
  }
}
```

[link here](https://jsfiddle.net/q9cvL7j4/)

Comment: What's the issue? I see the animation sliding in and then out

Comment: @JaredBledsoe on the fiddle? the fiddle does not work due the undefined event

Comment: Due to `display: none` your transitions do not show. If you change to visibility, you can see the transitions working

Answer (score 0):

The transition should be in `.single-page` element and you need add something like this after removing `hidden` class:

```
$('.sidebar').removeClass('hidden');
setTimeout(function() {$('.sidebar').addClass('sidebar-show');}, 0)
```

[link here](https://jsfiddle.net/vortin/a817cfae/)

Answer (score 0):

How about not using the class `hidden` on sidebar.

The transition itself `right:-100%` will hide the sidebar for you.

Also, take a look at http://css3please.com for the (probably) most up-to-date way of defining transition (and more) styles.

```js
  $('.panel a').on('click',function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var _thumbs =$(this).attr('data-name');
    show_content();
    $('#'+_thumbs).removeClass('hidden');
  });
  $('.close').on('click',function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
    hide_content();
    });

function hide_content(){
  $('.sidebar').removeClass('sidebar-show');
  $('.sidebar').on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(event) {
   $('.single-page').addClass('hidden');
   });
   
 }   
   
function show_content(){
 $(".sidebar").off( "webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend" );
 $('.single-page').addClass('hidden');
  
  $('.sidebar').addClass('sidebar-show')
}
```

```css
#container{
  background: red;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}
html{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
.sidebar{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:-100%;
  width: 500px;
  background: green;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Android 2.1+, Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6  */
          transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+  */
}

.sidebar-show{
  right:0;
}
.single-page{
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="panel">
      <a href="#" data-name="test1">test1</a>
      <a href="#" data-name="test2">test2</a>
      <a href="#" data-name="test3">test3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar ">
  <a href="" class="close">X</a>
  <div id="test1" class="single-page hidden">
    <h1>test1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto veniam dolorum praesentium perferendis? Dolorem nesciunt soluta delectus eum maxime blanditiis neque rerum officia molestiae nulla natus quo alias laudantium animi, omnis iste dolorum aliquam tenetur repellat ipsam esse, dicta est. Dolore aliquam inventore doloremque sint quasi expedita cupiditate, a. Excepturi!</p>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="test2" class="single-page hidden">
    <h1>test2</h1>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto veniam dolorum praesentium perferendis? Dolorem nesciunt soluta delectus eum maxime blanditiis neque rerum officia molestiae nulla natus quo alias laudantium animi, omnis iste dolorum aliquam tenetur repellat ipsam esse, dicta est. Dolore aliquam inventore doloremque sint quasi expedita cupiditate, a. Excepturi!</p>
    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="test3" class="single-page hidden">
    <h1>test3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto veniam dolorum praesentium perferendis? Dolorem nesciunt soluta delectus eum maxime blanditiis neque rerum officia molestiae nulla natus quo alias laudantium animi, omnis iste dolorum aliquam tenetur repellat ipsam esse, dicta est. Dolore aliquam inventore doloremque sint quasi expedita cupiditate, a. Excepturi!</p>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @GerryofTrivia Did this answer help you?